# Updated- Proof of convexity of trace function- is this argument correct

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-calculus, operator-algebras, trace

I am trying to understand Theorem 2 ($F(A,K) := \text{tr}(A^{-r}K^{\ast} A^{-p} K)$ is jointly convex for $p,r \geq 0$ and $p+r \leq 1$) of the paper [Convex trace functions and the Wigner-Yanase-Dyson conjecture](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(73)90011-X). I follow the steps and the argument (I think).

In my understanding, in order to prove that the function $F(A,K) := \text{tr}(A^{-r}K^{\ast} A^{-p} K)$ is convex, we differentiate the function $N(A,B,K,L)/D(A,B,K,L)$ where
$$N(A,B,K,L):= F(\lambda A + (1-\lambda)B, \lambda K + (1-\lambda)L)$$
and
$$D(A,B,K,L) := \lambda F(A,K) + (1-\lambda)F(B,L)$$

and show that if the maxima exists then $F$ must be convex. I do not understand why a maxima must exist.

**Update (3 Apr, 2023):** Here is a possible argument: In order to maximise $N/D$ both $K$ and $L$ can be chosen such that their norms (say $2$-norm) are at most $1$. To see this, suppose $\Vert K\Vert_2 \geq \Vert L\Vert_2$, then
$$\frac{N(A,B,K,L)}{D(A,B,K,L)} = \frac{N(A,B,K/\Vert K\Vert_2,L/\Vert K\Vert_2)}{D(A,B,K/\Vert K\Vert_2,L/\Vert K\Vert_2)}$$
and the operators $K/\Vert K\Vert_2,L/\Vert K\Vert_2$ both have norm at most $1$. In finite dimensions (which is assumed to be the case) there exists a maximum in the arguments $K,L$ for $N/D$ over the unit ball (call it $K_m, L_m$). Moreover, as a result of the above equation every value obtained by $N/D$ is obtained in the unit ball, which means a global maxima should also exist and must coincide with $K_m, L_m$. Hence, one can assume that a maxima exists for the function and in particular the derivatives can be set to $0$.

Is this argument correct?

---

Comment: Please consider transcribing the printscreen.

Comment: One shouldn't need to consult an external document just to get a complete statement of your problem.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4671026) and its cited reference may be helpful.